# Unable to log in to Jenkins after installation

Tags: jenkins, installation, passwords, homebrew, message

I installed Jenkins on my mac via brew.

As instructed, I have started the service, and navigated to:

http://localhost:8080

I expected to see this:

[image]

I am being asked for my username and password.

Instead, I seeing:

[image]

The user name I am using is admin

The password I am using is the password that was provided as part of the installation process.

This is not working. I am getting an Invalid username or password message.

Can someone please help me? I have installed / reinstalled etc.

Thank you, Sean

See below:

[image]

Comment: If you uninstall, you need to remove the JENKINS_HOME content, or look inside the secrets dir for the initialAdminPassword.

Answer (score 0):

you need to completely remove jenkins.

`sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist`

then install jenkins

`brew install jenkins`

Then  browse to `http://localhost:8080` you can access the first page of jenkins **Unlock Jenkins**

from there you can give the password and get into admin setup page. there you can set your username and password.